# Find the violated index on ORA-00001 (dup_val_on_index)

Tags: oracle, error-handling

I have a table with several indexes. In my application code there could be instances where any of these indexes could be violated, depending on user input.

I would like to log exactly which index was violated when my PL/SQL code stumbles upon an `ORA-00001`.

Is there a way to know which index violation caused Oracle to raise the `dup_val_on_index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AskTom has already discussed this](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3981863600346479794).

This could be achieved in following manner:

```
BEGIN
   -- code containing INSERT operation
EXCEPTION
   WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN
      Trace_SYS.Message(substr(sqlerrm, instr(sqlerrm, '(')+1,
                                        instr( sqlerrm, ')') - instr( sqlerrm,'(') -1 ));
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate expression for Oracle has implemented since regular expressions

**REGEXP_REPLACE(SQLERRM, '.*\((.*)\).*','\1')**